# How to inject a line feed to replace a delimiter

Tags: sed, replace, line, feed

```
/usr/bin/sed 's/,/\\n/g' comma-delimited.txt > newline-separated.txt
```

This doesn't work for me. I just get the ',' removed but the tokens are now just not delimited.

Answer (score 4):

You must have an older version of sed, so you need to put a literal LF char in your substitution, i.e.

```
/usr/bin/sed 's/,/
/g' comma-delimited.txt > newline-separated.txt
```

You may even need to escape the LF, so make sure there are no white space chars after the last char `'\'`

```
/usr/bin/sed 's/,/\
/g' comma-delimited.txt > newline-separated.txt
```

Comment: The second example works on AIX 6.1. Too often the only answers we get on UNIX questions pertain to Linux. Lots of enterprise developers are required to use IBM or HP systems.

Comment: Thanks. You'll find my answers typically use Sun4 syntaxes. More recentlyl I did 2 years with AIX, and I was glad that I knew the basics. Good luck to all!

Comment: thanks Shellter!, having the whole command on 1 line works: $ /usr/bin/sed 's/,//g' comma-delimited.txt > newline-separated.txt (is it implicit newline here?)

Comment: I'm surprised by that. Did you switch OS's or `sed` versions from your original question? Do you get any output from `sed --version`? Just be happy it works. Good luck to all.

Comment: Single quotes are your friend. Headdesk frustration using doubles quotes for a while. =(

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
echo a,b,c,d,e | sed 'G;:a;s/,\(.*\(.\)\)/\2\1/;ta;s/.$//'
a
b
c
d
e
```

Explanation:

- Appends a newline to the pattern space. `G`
- Substitute `,`'s with the last character in the pattern space i.e. the `\n` `:a;s/,\(.*\(.\)\)/\2\1/;ta`
- Remove the newline. `s/.$//`

Comment: I still get commas: $ echo a,b,c,d,e | sed 'G;:a;s/,\(.*\(.\)\)/\2\1/;ta;s/.$//'
a,b,c,d,e

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following, looks clumsy but does the work. Easy to understand. I use tr to do the replacement of the placeholder §. Only caveat is the placeholder, must be something NOT in the string(s).

```
ps -fu $USER | grep java | grep DML| sed -e "s/ -/§      -/g" | tr "§" "\n"
```

will give you an indented output of the commandline. DML is just some servername.

Answer (score -1):

on AIX7 answer #3 worked well:
I need to insert a newline at the beginning of a paragraph so I can do grep -p  to filter for 'mksysb' in the resulting 'stanza'
lsnim -l | /usr/bin/sed 's/^[a-zA-Z/\^J&/' 
(actually the initial line had an escaped newline:
   lsnim -l | /usr/bin/sed 's/^[a-zA-Z/\
   &/')
recalling the command showed the ^J syntax ...

Comment: what is `lsnim`? what does `^J syntax` have to do with all this? your answer does not clearly show how to answer the original poster's question